# How to convert response to object c#

Tags: c#, rest

I have build a simple .net client that call a simple rest web service. This works. The web services, return me this response:

```
    <Reply>
       <errorCode>OK</errorCode>
       <errorDescription>d13f2197-ed6e-4997-a06d-4166ca52aa75</errorDescription>
       <ccdContent></ccdContent>
    </Reply>
```

Now I want to retrieve this response how to Object. So I have create this class:

```
class Response
{
     [DataMember(Name = "errorCode")]
    String errorCode { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Name = "errorDescription")]
    String errorDescription{ set; get; }
}
```

And this is the method that call a web service:

```
public void writeSectionIntoCCD(String appID, String shardSecret, String userID, String password, String templateID)
{
    String currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    String URL = "https://dokumentti.it/";
    var client = new RestClient(URL);
    string hash = CalculateMD5Hash(currentTime + shardSecret + password);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("resource/ccd/problems/" + userID + "/" + appID + "/" + currentTime + "/" 
    + hash + "?starttime=20140615&code=275498002&name=Respiratorytractinfection&system=2.16.840.1.113883.6.96&systemname=SNOMED&statuscode=55561003&statusname=Active&statussystem=2.16.840.1.113883.6.96&statussystemname=SNOMED", Method.POST);
    IRestResponse<Response> response = client.Execute<Response>(request);

}
```

but the object is null.

Comment: Did you tag your class so that the `Response` class corresponds to the `Reply` node?

Comment: yes, I have insert the DataContract name also for the name of class Response but not works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but shouldn't you be doing something like:

```
RestResponse<Response> response = client.Execute<Response>(request);
var errorCode = response.Data.errorCode;
```

Comment: This is most likely a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yea, wondering if you should be grabbing the data like that. I think I remember something like it.  
Well, definitely your solution makes sense, you did not mark it as a contract and as thus it would not serialize.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, the problem are two:

I have insert this on the name of my class

```
[DataContract(Name = "Reply")]
```

then I have insert public attribute on my class. So now I have this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Reply")]
public class Response
{
     [DataMember(Name = "errorCode")]
    public String errorCode { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Name = "errorDescription")]
    public String errorDescription{ set; get; }
}
```